# Using log of function to determine orders of growth

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

If I have functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ and I would like to determine $f(n) \in \Omega g(n)$ and/or $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n)$.

Does proving $\log(f(n)) \in \Omega \log(g(n))$ imply $f(n) \in \Omega g(n)$?

And similarly for $\Theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=n^c$ for various positive values of $c$, then check which of the properties $f\in\Theta(g)$, $f\in\Omega(g)$, $\log f\in\Theta(\log g)$ and $\log f\in\Omega(\log g)$, hold. Then write down the answer to your question here.

Comment: Let $f(n) = n^4, g(n) = n^2$. The following properties hold: $\log(f) \in \Theta(\log(g))$, $f \in O(g)$. 

But if we let $f(n) = n^2, g(n) = n^4$, then $\log(f) \in \Theta(log(g))$, and $f \in \Omega(g)$.

So just given info about $\log(f), \log(g)$, I don't think I can infer anything about the complexity of $f$ w.r.t. $g$?

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $